# Android License Server Check always times out

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm trying to implement The Android LicenseChecker in my app, and I've followed the instructions almost verbatim  from the developer site.  Everything seems hooked up correctly, but every single time I get the "Check timed out." message.

I increased the timeout value to 30 seconds, I'm logged into my device (which has the market app installed) with my publisher account login gmail address.  I set the test response to Licensed.  I saved (but didn't publish) a sample app to test with.  When that didn't work, I tried using an app that is already published and just rebuilding the apk locally to include the LVL implementation... what am I doing wrong?

I definitely have 3g connectivity. I can browse the web on the device and other connected apps are working correctly.  Please help.

Comment: It's weird. I have 3G, too, in Brazil (not the best connections, but not bad). Here it's just a matter of setting the license "dumb test" response on the Market profile and it works. Maybe you could tell us what you did differently? Btw, I didn't answer with this tip because I assume you are doing that on your profile. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like a dumb question, so apologies if that's the case, but did you add Internet access to your app in the manifest file?

I only ask because I was stuck scratching my head quite awhile last night after having a similar problem, only to find that I had entirely forgot to set my apps permissions. D'OH!

Comment: Yes I did.  In fact, my app had Internet permissions before I started on the licensing server stuff.  Anyway, I double checked and it's def. there...

Answer (score 0):

Use android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and see what your application is reporting to you about your network connectivity.